# How to set scale and bias in CatBoost R package

Tags: r, normalization, catboost

The catboost documentation contains instructions for setting model scale and bias in the Python package ([here](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/python-reference_catboostregressor_set_scale_and_bias.html)) and the command line implementation ([here](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/cli-reference_normalize-model.html)), but not the R package.

Can anyone show how it is done in R?